# PagerAdapter with only one Fragment that is instantiate

Tags: android

I would like to use a PagerAdapter but I want to instantiate only the showing Fragment.
In onDestroy I call this:

```
@Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
        Log.i("REMOVE", "destroyItem() [position: " + position + "]" + " childCount:" + container.getChildCount());
    }
```

For example if I am at position 3 the fragment at position 2 and 4 is also instantiated. How can I destroy all Items except the showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

They are needed for the swipe animation.

If you only need one fragment to be instantiated at any given time, you should drop the `ViewPager` and use `FragmentTransaction.replace()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!